# Camera showing black (Emulator)

Tags: android, android-emulator, camera, android-debug

When I step through my code in the debugger, the camera emulator works as it should.  When I run it in the emulator (not stepping though the debugger), I get a black screen as the camera view.  The Camera object is NOT = null (I Logged to check).  I am getting a camera, everything looks ok, but I still get the black screen.  I do have get a Camera error 100 but I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a hardware device there is no issue.  i guess the emulator doesn't currently work for a camera unless its is being stepped through with the debugger.  As long as it works on hardware then its not a huge problem